# Ruby method with local variable - a case of simple refactoring

Tags: ruby

My method is currently like this:

```
def calculate
  bill = 0
  order.each {|k, v| bill += restaurant.show_menu[k]*v}
  bill  
end
```

It looks really ugly, but I need it to return `bill`. Thought about making `bill` an instance variable and hence define it when my object initializes, but I don't use it anywhere else. Whats the best way to refactor this?

Comment: It appears that `order` and `restaurant` are methods, but you've provided no explanation. Please elaborate.

Comment: why you think it is upgly? what is wrong with local variables?

Comment: There are few Ruby ways to solve exactly this kind of problem.

Comment: @Meier, there's nothing wrong with local variables, but each time one is used there's one more potential source of errors. If, for example, in one place you had `ugly = 4` and later misspelled the variable and wrote `upgly = 7` (improbable as that might be), you've got one more bug to squash.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is one possible way:

```
 def calculate
    order.reduce(0) {|bill, (k, v)| bill + restaurant.show_menu[k]*v}
 end
```

Comment: thank you. I've seen reduce method before but I didn't know to use it for this case.

Comment: @ggwc You may want to accept an answer if it helps.. Have a look at [how to accept an answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/226854).  You will get +2 points, many new users seems to miss on accepting answers.  Your previous question had a good answer, please accept that one as well.    It's okay to wait for few hours or few days before accepting if you are not satisfied with current answers.

Comment: @ggwc you can also separate the steps using `map` and `reduce`, e.g. `order.map { |k, v| restaurant.show_menu[k] * v }.reduce(0, :+)`

Answer (score 3):

```
def calculate
  order.map { |k, v| restaurant.show_menu[k] * v }.reduce(:+)
end
```

---

`map` to return an array contains of the values; `reduce` to apply the `:+` method on each element, which means to sum them up.